# AWS Amplify change environment based on user

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify, aws-appsync

I have a mobile app build in React Native and I am using Amplify and Cognito for user authentication. Now, I want that certain users access the environment "env1" and others access "env2".

Currently we use `amplify env checkout prod` to switch between dev and prod environment. Once the app is released to the app store, we cannot change the environment anymore.

How can I achieve that Amplify connects to a different environment based on the Cognito user?